# Forge Server Crashing

Tags: server, crash, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I have no idea what I am doing wrong. Any help is appreciated! Everything below is the log I have from the console. Some background is that the modpack itself is fairly unstable but I have never had this much trouble with it. It usually works fine only needing a couple restarts but today it won't even boot at all.
https://hastebin.skyra.pw/ewukelopil.bash
I tried removing mods mentioned as having errors and I also tried looking for others with similar crashes.